# Solve Burr Puzzles in Blender?

Tags: edit-mode, collision

There is a great software called [BurrTools](http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/) for the automated solving of burr puzzles, it is however sometimes a little bit cumbersome to work with.

[image: examples of burr puzzles]

I do not think that there is any equal function in Blender, but I'm looking for other ways that Blender might assist in the design, manipulation and solving of such puzzles.

One particular function I'm interested in is basically having a collision detection in *Object Mode*, such that you could only move the objects in a way it would also be possible in reality, i.e. that prevents you from moving the objects through or into each other.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: This requires a lot of fine tuning to make for a realistic "game", but it's possible, yes.

Comment: Blender has a builtin *Rigid Body* physics system that should be able to do this easily, unfortunately I don't think it deals too well with "tight fitting" parts and attaching pieces like this. Constraints are a lot more suited, but setting them up for something like this would be a lot of manual work and prone to errors.

Comment: It would be great if Blender could figure out why this, Rigid Body physics, doesn't work. I tried to use physics to allow an object to rest within an eyelet, it would do so, only to jiggle and vibrate till it forced through the eyelet. It seems it doesn't like things to get 'too' close. So much for being rigid enough.